# displaying deadline tasks only once in org-mode weekly agenda

Tags: emacs, org-mode

In agenda view I see deadlined tasks listed on the days they're due AND on the days immediately prior. Is there any way for agenda to display a task only once (preferably on the earliest day it would appear) without disabling the advance warning entirely?

Comment: Have a look at the variable `org-deadline-warning-days`.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not trying to change the number of warning days. I just want the item appear only once in the agenda, instead of reappearing every day up till the deadline.

Answer (score 1):

What you ask is not possible. It defeats the concept of the agenda itself.

However, for specific items, you can add a pre-warning (of 0d, for example) such as:

```
** TODO Show me
   DEADLINE: <2014-08-15 Fri -0d>
```

OK, that does not help you straight away, except that:

- without pre-warning, it will use the global warning period (7 or 14 d, by default)
- on the items you want to change, do `C-u C-u C-c C-d` to add/change the local pre-warning date

That's manual, but you could have an Emacs macro to help you.